# Atributo de tipo "clase" : no entiendo nada!

Tags: java

Buenas tardes. Estoy haciendo DAW y empieza a complicarse el asunto y estoy algo perdido. Os pego la parte del enunciado y que no entiendo resaltado en negrita:

En esta tarea se van a realizar un conjunto de clases que permitan modelar las distintos tipos de cuentas que una persona puede tener en un banco, haciendo uso del mecanismo de herencia. Los puntos que se deben tratar para resolver la tarea son:

Crear un proyecto en NetBeans denominado, "CuentasBancarias".

Dentro de dicho proyecto, crear un paquete denominado "modeloBancario".

Dentro del paquete "modeloBancario", crear una clase denominada Cliente, que modele los distintos clientes del banco que tienen una cuenta asociada para almacenar su dinero. Las características de la clase Cliente son:

Atributos (Todos los atributos de la clase Cliente deben tener visibilidad privada):

**idCliente**: número entero que representa el identificador único del cliente dentro del banco.
**nombre**: cadena de caracteres que representa el nombre del cliente del banco.

**direccion**: cadena de caracteres que representa la dirección donde vive el cliente del banco.
**teléfono**: cadena de caracteres que representa el teléfono que permite contactar con el cliente.

Métodos (Todos los métodos de la clase Cliente deben tener visibilidad pública):

constructor sin parámetros: constructor que inicializa todos los atributos de tipo cadenas de caracteres al valor null y los números enteros a 0.
constructor con parámetros: constructor que tienen tantos parámetros como atributos tiene la clase, y que inicializa cada uno de los atributos con el valor de los parámetros correspondientes.

Dentro del paquete "modeloBancario", crear una clase abstracta denominada "Cuenta", que modele las distintas cuentas bancarias que mantiene la entidad financiera donde los clientes depositan su dinero.
Atributos (Todos los atributos de la clase Cuenta deben tener visibilidad protegida)

**numeroDeCuenta**: número entero que representa el identificador único asociado a cada una de las cuentas del banco.

**saldo**: número real que representa la cantidad de dinero almacenado en dicha cuenta.

***titular: atributo de tipo Cliente que representa la persona que está asociada a dicha cuenta.***

Métodos (Todos los métodos de la clase Cuenta deben tener visibilidad pública)
constructor sin parámetros: constructor que inicializa el cliente titular de la cuenta a null, y el saldo y el número de cuenta a cero.
constructor con parámetros: constructor que tienen tantos parámetros como atributos tiene la clase, y que inicializa cada uno de los atributos con el valor de los parámetros correspondientes.

Ahí me pierdo, no entiendo que quiere decir  "tipo Cliente". Osea, debe de ser que ese atributo sea la clase entera llamada "Cliente". Os pongo lo que he hecho hasta ahora:

Clase "Cliente":

```
package modeloBancario;

public class Cliente {

private int idCliente;
private String nombre;
private String direccion;
private String telefono;

public Cliente (){

}

public Cliente (int idCliente, String nombre, String direccion, String telefono){

    this.idCliente = idCliente;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.direccion = direccion;
    this.telefono = telefono;

}

public int getIdCliente(){
    return idCliente;
}

public void setIdCliente(int idCliente){
    this.idCliente = idCliente;
}

public String getNombre(){
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre){
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getDireccion(){
    return direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(String direccion){
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public String getTelefono(){
    return telefono;
}

public void setTelefono(String telefono){
    this.telefono = telefono;
}
}
```

Y la clase "Cuenta":

```
package modeloBancario;

public abstract class Cuenta {

protected int numeroDeCuenta;
protected double saldo;
protected Cliente titular;

public Cuenta(){

    numeroDeCuenta = 0;
    saldo = 0;
    titular ();

}
}
```

Agradeceria una pista, llevo dias atascado!

Comment: Creo que deberias declarar la variable cliente como clase
private Cliente cliente;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando creaste la clase Cliente este se puede usar como un tipo de dato, por lo cual debes hacer lo siguiente :

```
package modeloBancario;

public abstract class Cuenta {

    protected int numeroDeCuenta;
    protected double saldo;
    protected Cliente titular;

    public Cuenta() {

        numeroDeCuenta = 0;
        saldo = 0;
        titular = null;
    }

    public Cuenta(int numeroDeCuenta, double saldo, Cliente titular){

        this.numeroDeCuenta = numeroDeCuenta;
        this.saldo = saldo;
        this.titular = titular;
    }
}
```

Comment: De acuerdo, pero entonces...¿que tipo de dato puede llevar el atributo cliente? Antes era `int`, por lo que se rellenaría con un número entero, ¿pero ahora?

    Y luego la clase "Cuenta", ¿iria asi?

    `public abstract class Cuenta {

    protected int numeroDeCuenta;
    protected double saldo;
    protected Cliente titular;

    public Cuenta(){

    numeroDeCuenta = 0;
    saldo = 0;
    titular ();

}`

Comment: me parece que tu ejemplo esta mal.. el atributo cliente lo tiene la clase cuenta. y si, cuenta tiene un puntero a la clase cliente (un atributo de tipo cliente). @MeN no pienses en base de datos.. estas en objetos, y los objetos se relacionan por si mismos.

Comment: Sí, mi ejemplo estaba mal, ya lo correji

Comment: Gracias chicos, creo que he dado un pasito en la comprensión. Pero no entiendo por que se hace eso ni que implicaciones tiene. Por ejemplo, se que `saldo` va a ser un numero, `numeroDeCuenta` tambien, pero ´titular´ que será? Apunta a una clase, no se que sale de ahí. ¿Apunta a todos los atributos de clase?

Comment: Es un Objeto, al mandarle el objeto Cliente  a la clase Cuenta desde cuenta podrás usar todas las propiedades de cliente trata de investigar lo básico de la programación orientada a objetos y y si la respuesta resolvió tu problema marcarla como correcta, saludos :)

Comment: Gracias, todo bastante aclarado. No lo entontraba en ningun sitio todo esto pero...al usar todas las propiedades de cliente desde cuenta, ¿no es como una herencia? Sigo sin entender con que valores podria inicializar el atributo ´titular´ pero bueno, seguiré estudiando. Saludos :)